# query to copy a node with relations in neo4j without the clone procedure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to copy a node with all its properties and relations with others nodes. Im using Neo4j version 3.4.7 so I can't use the clone procedure. My node might have different types of relations and I want to copy them all. I wanted to use this query

```
match (map:student {name:'test'})
create (copy:student) set copy=map with copy,map
match (map)-[r1]->(n)
with collect(r1) as rels,map,copy,n
foreach( rel in rels | create (copy)-[r2:type(rel)]->(n) set r2+=rel)
return copy,n
```

but I get invalid syntax error using type(rel) in foreach. Is there a way to do this without knowing the types of relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to [install the APOC library](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/installation/), and call the procedure `apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships`, as documented [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/graph-refactoring/clone-nodes/).

In your case, your query would become:

```
MATCH (map:student {name:'test'})
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships([map])
```

Note: node labels usually start with an upper letter (`Student` is more common than `student` in Neo4j datasets).

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked for me although I had to use your query with yield and return just like the document.